# Twitter Bootstrap won't allow height:100% on small screens, tried all described solutions from other questions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried all possible ways to set the height so that the page is filled on mobile etc small screens just the way it is filled on large screens but it keeps folding.

Please suggest any solutions you may think of.

The problem can be seen at the following address:
http://lakeeya.com/

Log in with the credentials: 'test@lakeeya.com'
pass: 'Test2014'

Forgot to add, it is the "Messages page" I'm having issues with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add below styles

In footer tag

```
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
```

In section tag

```
background-color: #2c3039;
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
bottom: 0;
```

I am attaching a screen shot of mobile view, Please see if this is what you are trying to achieve http://awesomescreenshot.com/061390elde

I am assuming that you are using some media query to differentiate style between mobile and desktop.

Comment: Thanks for that will try in 15 min. The screenshot you attached describes precisely what I need to achieve, as it will be a webview app. I use Bootstrap's standard features to differentiate devices i.e. It is dependent on the viewport size, would you recommend anything different? Thanks. Vladyslav

Comment: So I have modified it slightly, set the width to 100% which solved it, but if you click refresh button to load messages, and open one of them, if the same css is applied to that "section" & "footer" it doesn't work, but instead makes the section invisible & footer not being pulled down. Can you please take a look, since it still does not work properly. Appreciate your help

Comment: @LifeStrike The problem you mentioned, I am unable to find it. On the other hand you have to add position: absolute; width: 100%; in the header also. Because the tooltip is hiding below as of now, when I click on reload.
http://awesomescreenshot.com/018391ag6d
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e8391ah05

Comment: Just setting the width wasn't enough but I solved it by setting left:0;right:0; Thanks for heading me in the right direction though :)

Answer (score 0):

Disable inline style: `display: table-cell;` in `section id="content"`.
Also, as angel stated, consider using media queries.

I would also recommend changing `nav` to have smaller width in mobile mode.